# laravel 5.6 JQuery wont work in my project and i load it in my script

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

i loaded the jQuery footer_meta.blade.php

```
<script src="{{asset('control/js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('control/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('control/js/scripts.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('control/js/jquery.slimscroll.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('control/js/flot-chart/excanvas.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('control/js/jquery.scrollTo.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('control/asset/plugins/jquery.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and when i use it in my view index.blade.php nothing happen

```
@section('script')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('welcome');
    })
</script>
@endsection
```

i get this in the console
[image: console]

Comment: is there any console error? Are you include this in the main layout page. @include('footer_meta'); or are you  used yield for sections?

Comment: Does your `index.blade.php` extend your `layouts/app.blade.php`? Do you `@yield` that section "script" there?

Comment: That happens because you're loading jQuery lib twice, try to remove one of the includes, and move it to the top.

Comment: yes it extend and i have yeilds for all the header,body ,footer ... ,,  zakira what do u mean with move it with to the top .. i dont uderstand

Comment: which include should i remove ?

Comment: Zakira was talking about your `<script>` tags/includes. You load jquery twice: `jquery.min.js` and `jquery-1.12.4.min.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing your page section then writing the script.

The best way is to @endsection at the end of the page. It should be like this and jquery must be define in the header section of your page

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('welcome');
})
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: "_The best way is to @endsection at the end of the page._" What? Why? What if I have multiple sections? And btw, OP has `@endsection` is his code

Comment: i am asking about the content section that you are working

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. What content section?

Comment: Ok I am explaining you.
@section('content')
 your script should be here. This is my point.
@endsection

Comment: "_@section('content') your script should be here._" Well, no, it shouldn't. The script can be in a different section on that page. Or in a `@stack()`.